# NullPointerException generated when using Grails Promises

Tags: grails, groovy, promise

I'm using Grails 2.5.6. I've got a Promise being created in a controller that, on completion, sporadically errors out and I can't figure out why. Here's a minimal implementation:

```
// FooController.groovy
def bar()
{
  Promises.task {
    log.debug "Hello, Test!"
  }.onComplete {
    log.debug "Complete!"
  }.onError {
    log.debug "Error!"
  }
  render "OK"
}
```

The first time I open "foo/bar" in the browser I see "OK" as expected, and the log shows

```
2018-05-01 16:00:17,311 [Actor Thread 1] DEBUG - Hello, Test!
2018-05-01 16:00:17,322 [Actor Thread 2] DEBUG - Complete!
```

as expected. However, the next time I load it I get an exception:

```
2018-05-01 16:00:21,890 [Actor Thread 4] DEBUG - Hello, Test!
Error |
2018-05-01 16:00:21,896 [Actor Thread 6] ERROR gpars.LoggingPoolFactory  - Async execution error: null
Message: null
    Line | Method
->> 1513 | notifyAttributeAssigned in org.apache.catalina.connector.Request
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1503 | setAttribute            in     ''
|    539 | setAttribute . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade
|    283 | setAttribute            in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest
|    431 | storeGrailsWebRequest . in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils
|     55 | doCall                  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.async.WebRequestPromsiseDecorator$_decorate_closure1
|     -1 | call . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     61 | doCall                  in org.grails.async.factory.gpars.GparsPromise$_onComplete_closure1
|     -1 | call . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     62 | run                     in groovyx.gpars.dataflow.DataCallback$1
|   1142 | runWorker . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run                     in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Note that on the second run the `onError` closure doesn't get called. I traced the exception down to the following line in `org.apache.catalina.connector.Request` but that's as far as I got:

```
private void notifyAttributeAssigned(String name, Object value, Object oldValue) {
  Context context = this.getContext();
  Object[] listeners = context.getApplicationEventListeners();
                              ^-- NullPointerException thrown here
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I don't see what. I've been banging my head against this for a long time -- please help?

Comment: **Update**: I tried replacing the `log.debug` calls with `System.out.println` after reading [this comment from Graeme Rocher](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9896#issuecomment-219718186), but I'm still seeing errors similar to the above sporadically thrown from the `onComplete` and `onError` handlers in `GparsPromise.groovy`.

Comment: Have you ever figured this out? I'm encountering the same exception and so far have no idea what is causing it.

Comment: @PepijnSchmitz sorry, I don't remember how I resolved this. Ultimately the resolution may have been "use a newer version of Grails" but I understand that's not always an option.